# jQuery - Sort an array and add a class to values with the same attribute, and the top 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**Scenario**:

- I am matching cases up via using the distance between two points
  (using lat and long).
- Everything is done in a table.
- I get a list of 'tds' with class 'city', and make an array.
- Then I sort the array based on 'data-distance' attribute
- I then highlight the top ten, and if two 'data-distance' has the same
  value, highlight them both, and then highlight, lets say 11 instead
  of 10, because two have the same 'data-distance'

This is a screenshot of what I currently have, and an overview:
[image]

At the moment, it currently highlights the top ten, and if two values are the same, highlight them the same color, but it does not hightlight another one after 10.


**Current Code**

```
var c_tds = $('td.city');
var c_arr = $.makeArray(c_tds);
c_arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  var A = $(a).attr('data-distance');
  var B = $(b).attr('data-distance');
  return B - A;
});
for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
  var A1 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-i]);      var A2 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-(i-1)]);
  if(A1.attr('data-distance') == A2.attr('data-distance')){ console.log(A1); }
  A1.addClass('success');
}

for ( var i = 6; i <= 10; i++ ) {
  var B1 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-i]);      var B2 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-(i-1)]);
  if(B1.attr('data-distance') == B2.attr('data-distance')){ console.log(i); if(i == 6) { B1.addClass('success'); } else { B1.addClass('warning'); } } else {
    B1.addClass('warning');
  }
}
```

**Question**

How can I get it so that if two values are the same, then add an extra one to highlight (keeping the minimum highlight count of 10)

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @blgt added extra information

Comment: Why you don't use [table-sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed the magic number 10 to a mutable variable:

```
var maxHighlightsLength = 10;
for ( var i = 6; i <= maxHighlightsLength ; i++ ) {
  var B1 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-i]);      var B2 = $(c_arr[c_arr.length-(i-1)]);
  if(B1.attr('data-distance') == B2.attr('data-distance')){ maxHighlightsLength++; if(i == 6) { B1.addClass('success'); } else { B1.addClass('warning'); } } else {
    B1.addClass('warning');
  }
}
```

Note that this way you get a corner case where *everything* is highlighted. You might want to add special handling for it (You can do the same for both loops)

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnu7p/)

**JS**

```
function highlightTopTen() {
    var tds = $( "td.city" );
    tds.sort( function( td1, td2 ) {
        return parseInt( $( td2 ).attr( "data-distance" ) ) - parseInt( $( td1 ).attr( "data-distance" ) );
    } );
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++ ) {
        if ( i > 0 && parseInt( $( tds[ i ] ).attr( "data-distance" ) ) != parseInt( $( tds[ i - 1 ] ).attr( "data-distance" ) ) ) { j++; }
        if ( j >= 10 ) {
            break;
        } else {
            $( tds[ i ] ).addClass( "highlited" );
        }
    }
}
```